# Throttling or adding delays between OnTriggerEnter2D calls

Tags: unity, c#, c

I have 2 game objects: `Explosion` and `Enemy`. At any given point, an enemy can collide with multiple `Explosion` game objects at the same exact time. This causes a few issues when I'm trying to destroy the `Enemy` game object.

This is the function that destroys the game object:

```
bool isDead = false;

public void KillCharacter () {
  if (!isDead) {
    isDead = true;
    Debug.Log ("kill enemy...");
  }
}
```

If I use `OnTriggerEnter2D` inside the `Enemy` script, like so:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
  if (other.gameObject.tag == "Explosion") {
    KillCharacter();
  }
}
```

In case two explosions spawn on the position of the enemy, `Debug.Log` inside the `KillCharacter` function will fire twice, even though I set the `isDead` bool to true on the first run.

The only solution I found was to call `KillCharacter` from the `Explosion` script, like so:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
  if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
    other.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy> ().KillCharacter ();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to run the `OnTriggerEnter2D` from the `Enemy` script, as I originally intended? Or is having the `KillCharacter` handle all the death logic and calling it from outside good enough?

Comment: The behavior you describe shouldn't really happen -- you set `isDead` to true the first time, so even if two collisions are happening at a nearly identical time, they must still be handled sequentially in some way, and the very first one closes the processing for the second. Could you check your code some more to see if either the `isDead` is perhaps set to false somewhere again -- or that maybe your script is attached to two different gameObjects, and you are mistaking the "kill enemy" debug log for a single gameObject? E.g. give all objects a different name and use `print("killed " + name)`.

Comment: please share full scriptd

Answer (score 0):

Tested your question and code out as at first I thought it was regarding the 'Is Trigger' option on the collider.
However, it's working as intended.

As shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBWfs.jpg.

> The script is on the Enemy tagged object. Tested with the 'Is Trigger' checked on one and both of the Objects "Enemy", "Explosion".

The only thing I changed from your code was set the `bool isDead` to `public` so that it shows on the inspector.

Most likely problem is that your bool `isDead` is being altered elsewhere.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Unity v2019.3.0f6. Not sure if it makes a difference, but the explosions spawn on the location of the enemy at the same time, not the other way around. I tried logging inside `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `KillCharacter` and it shows like this: https://i.imgur.com/DsBnJy4.png - `isDead` is set to true before the first `killed char` log is output. This is really weird.

Comment: `using same version` When you spawn(instantiate) the explosions they are happening sequentially through each instantiation line and not at the exact same time, so it shouldn't be possible for a double trigger. I recommend that you debug by creating new explosion and enemy objects with just the code above attached to the enemy object and see if that works as you intended.